# Pixelated and smooth text in Microsoft Powerpoint using same font/size/etc

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm using the "Title and Content" layout for one of my pages, and somehow the Title content becomes very smooth and looks good, but the content is very pixelated.
I'm running powerpoint 2007.

Any clues on how to overcome this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### PowerPoint 2016 Fix

1. Right click and select **format** for anything on your page.
2. This will bring up the right side **Format Shape** options panel.
3. Select the problematic aliased text box.
4. Make sure you don't select the actual text, you want the outline.

   - *I press the <kbd>**`Esc`**</kbd> key once selected so it's just the outline*
5. Under the **Format Shape** select **Text Options**.
6. Click the first tab, which is letter A for me with a bold underline.
7. Click **Gradient fill**, and not solid fill.
8. Leave the color as black, and this appears to apply a nice anti-aliased effect to the text block.

Comment: Adding  1% transparency to the text has also worked for me, without really being noticeable

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I would say that you do not have the font installed that the content is using.

So Windows is falling back on a bitmapped font.

Check what font the text is using and then go into `C:\Windows\Fonts` and search for that font.

Or simply change the font to Arial (temporarily) to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi,
It doesn't matter which font I'm used, the two different fields have the same font, it's just a matter of some sort of "option" that's been enabled/disabled on one of them that makes them look different, but I just can't find it it seems

Comment: Hmm, I only have 2010 installed right now and I can't find any setting that would cause this. The normal reason for this in Windows is that the font file itself is missing or corrupted so that Windows is substituting something else.

Comment: Well I guess using the same font on both types of content kinda rules not-having-the-font out, don't you agree? But yeah I'll continue searching or make the presentation anyway, but it looks a bit silly.